# How does nivo calculate the width of the bars on a chart?

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, visualization, nivo-react

I want to dynamically allow the labels on the bar charts depending on the width of the bars - if it gets to thin the labels are not looking good and often overlap. However I don't really want to mess with some low-level SVG element manipulation and nivo has to use something to calculate the width of the bars; I could use the same thing to determine if the labels will fit. I'm expecting something from d3 directly, but I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I went through the nivo's source code and after some searching I found what I was looking for (sort of) [here](https://github.com/plouc/nivo/blob/44d8967e774dc4d11d2d1f48513e102dcb4688e9/packages/bar/src/compute/grouped.ts#L228):

```js
const bandwidth = (indexScale.bandwidth() - innerPadding * (keys.length - 1)) / keys.length
```

This is the version for the grouped bar chart (as opposed to stacked, but in that case it's simply `= indexScale.bandwidth()`), where `innerPadding` is the padding between the bars in the group and `keys` are the keys used for a single group. The `indexScale`, however, is an internal object created with (I'm simplifying) `createBandScale`, which you can see [here](https://github.com/plouc/nivo/blob/master/packages/scales/src/bandScale.ts#L4):

```js
export const createBandScale = <Input extends StringValue>(
    { round = true }: ScaleBandSpec,
    data: ComputedSerieAxis<Input>,
    size: number,
    axis: ScaleAxis
) => {
    const scale = scaleBand<Input>()
        .range(axis === 'x' ? [0, size] : [size, 0])
        .domain(data.all)
        .round(round)

    return castBandScale<Input>(scale)
}
```

This function is available through `@nivo/scales`, so I could use it for my purposes. However, after doing some testing I discovered that my results were off - the computations seem to ignore the padding between the groups and so the width I was calculating was greater than the actual bar width; I don't know why that is, perhaps this is considered somewhere further along the line, but for my purposes I just needed to create a `BandScale` like this:

```js
const bandScale = createBandScale(
    { round: false },
    { all: xAxis },
    totalWidth,
    "x"
).paddingInner(padding) // << this is the important part
```

The only challenge left was figuring out the total width of the SVG element and fortunately nivo's codebase has this kind of hook, but it is not a part of the package, so I ended up adding it to my own code - [here](https://github.com/plouc/nivo/blob/44d8967e774dc4d11d2d1f48513e102dcb4688e9/packages/core/src/hooks/useMeasure.js#L3) is the hook.